# how can I login the wp admin panel with the cpanel

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I want to login the wp admin panel.
I have the cpanel info but lost the wp admin password and I can`t reset the password too by using the email access.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi Eric check this http://www.devlounge.net/publishing/reset-a-wordpress-password-from-phpmyadmin

Comment: I tried to do this with the database user field but there is the db info in the wp-config file but there is no database in the phpmyadmin. How can I find the database in the cpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login to CPANEL, open phpmyadmin.
2. Browser wp_users table, find admin user and click on it.
3. In password field, paste this code: $P$BC8pg.B8hK6gjPJqV2aYl9JPq0cMNx/
4. Save it and login to example.com/wp-admin with your username and 123456 password.
5. Immediately change your password after logging in.

FYI, the hashed password in 3rd step is output of WP hash function wp_hash_password('123456')

UPD:
i have just seen your comment to another answer: Are you sure that at left sidebar of phpmyadmin there is no DB choise? Sometimes when you login to phpmyadmin no DB is visible until you choose DB from left sidebar selectbox.

UPD2:
If you can't solve the problem with PHPMyadmin, then try creating new user via PHP.

1. Browse files via file manager and open your active theme folder.
2. in header.php (or footer.php, doesn't matter) add this code to the end

   ```
   <?php 
   $user_id = wp_create_user( 'some_unique_name','any_password','some_unique_name@example.com' );
   $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
   $user->set_role( 'administrator' );
   ?>
   ```

Open your website once. Then remove that code from header.php.

And now you can login to your website with newly created username.

Comment: The db connection info is in the wp-config.php file, however the database doesn`t show in the phpmyadmin.
How can I find the db in the phpmyadmin?

Comment: i can't say anything about that as i haven't seen your cpanel from inside. But you can do same change via code. Now i am adding that trick to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One is using Mysql.

> Log into your hosting cPanel. Click phpMyAdmin under the Databases
>   heading. On the left, click the username, then the specific database
>   (you may need to find this in your wp-config file if you aren't sure
>   which database). Click wp_users. The username and email are listed
>   here and you can click Edit to the right to change them. The password
>   is listed in MD5 hash. To change it, you will need to click Edit on
>   the left, then enter the new password, and select MD5 in the drop-down
>   menu under Functions.

You can solve them using losting password option
Using the Lost Password option

> 1. Open your WordPress administrative login page – it is usually located in http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin.
> 2. Click on the Lost your password? option, fill out the username or email address > Get New Password:
> 3. Log into your email account, which is set as your administrative WordPress contact. You can find the email message with the password
>      reset URL there, click on it:
> 4. Enter your new strong password twice on the opened page > Reset password:

You can solve them easy using ftp connection also .
-If you have username

> Using an FTP client connect to your WordPress website. Navigate to the
>   directory of the WordPress theme which is currently enabled on your
>   blog or website. WordPress themes can be found in \wp-config\themes\
>   directory. Download the file functions.php of your WordPress theme.
>   Add the below line of code after the first http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin. Login to WordPress using the
>   default administrator account name (typically admin) using the
>   password password. Once you submit the credentials (try to login) the
>   login page will simply reload without redirecting you to the WordPress
>   dashboard. This means you  have just reset the WordPress administrator
>   password to password. Do not try to login again for now. Each time you
>   try to login, you will reset the WordPress administrator account
>   password. Before trying to login again, using the FTP client download
>   the modified functions.php file from the themes directory. Remove the
>   line you have added before, save the changes and upload back the file.

Or not.

> Once connected to your WordPress site, you need to locate your
>   WordPress theme’s functions.php file. It would be at a location like
>   this: /yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/your-current-theme/functions.php
>   Right click on functions.php file and then select download. Your FTP
>   client will download the functions.php file to your computer. Open the
>   file you just downloaded on your computer using a plain text editor
>   like Notepad. Now you need to add this code at the bottom of the file.

```
function wpb_admin_account(){
$user = 'Username';
$pass = 'Password';
$email = 'email@domain.com';
if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
$user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->set_role( 'administrator' );
} }
add_action('init','wpb_admin_account');
```

> Don’t forget to replace Username, Password, and email@domain.com with
>   your own values. Next, save the file and then upload it back to your
>   website using the FTP client. You can now visit your WordPress site’s
>   login area and sign in with the user account you just added. Once you
>   have logged in to your WordPress site, please edit the functions.php
>   file and delete the code you added. Deleting the code will not remove
>   the user you added, and you can always add new users and authors to
>   your WordPress site.

Tian Yang